# My web page is opening from local server but after opening external hyperlinks are not working

Tags: html

I have tried putting [ brackes ] before and after link.

When I insert hyperlink it also converts to file location

I have tried ///// five forward slashes after writting file

Nothing is working out.

Comment: I want to excess that web page from  a network location

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Web page was nothing but a excel file saved as htm at that i had attached various hyperlinks placed at that same network addr folder. But when i was placing the path of that htm file at our site it was not navigating so i decided to save that htm file at local server so that atleast that file gets open and after that hyperlinks on that htm page will work but it is not happening..after sa ving locally htm file is getting open but links on it not working, kindly guide a way to access the page and its links without saving them at local server.

Answer (score 0):

You can always load local HTML files into a web browser and it will (typically) interpret your code without issues. However, in order to have a website that's accessible from outside of your own computer, you need a running and well-configured web server. 
 Could you please specify what programming language or languages are you working with (PHP, JavaScript, C#.Net, for example)? And what operating system platform are you using, or intending to use, as a server? I.e.: Windows, macOS, Ubuntu, etc.
Your response will give us a better idea of what you have and how to help you. Cheers!